# How to handle if response from server is null in android?

Tags: android

I am sending server request to handle response and error i have implemented interface. I just want to know how to handle if "mResultCallBack ==null" without editing condition if(mResultCallBack!=null). code are as follow:-

```
public Context mContext;
private IResult mResultCallBack;

public CServerRequest(IResult mResultCallBack, Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResultCallBack = mResultCallBack;
}

public void postWalletRequest(final String requestType, String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                mResultCallBack.notifySuccess(requestType, response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                mResultCallBack.notifyError(requestType, error);

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

and code for interface

```
  public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response);
public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error);




AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (loginSessionManager.isLogin()){
                cServerRequest = new CServerRequest(mResultcallBack,mContext);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put(CRequestKey.AGENT_CODE, m_szMobileNumber.trim());// sending mobile no.(static right know becuse of ser side data on other is null
                    jsonObject.put(CRequestKey.PIN, m_szEncryptedPassword.trim());// same here as said above
                    Log.e(TAG,"Request::"+jsonObject.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final String s_szWalletURL = CAPIStorage.IREWARDS_URL + CAPIStorage.WALLET_BALANCE_URL;
                cServerRequest.postWalletRequest("POST",s_szWalletURL,jsonObject);


            }else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Not loggedin");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Handle according to your needs.

Comment: Just make `Toast` as result like "Please check your connection and try again". I think this is better toast to user.

Comment: @NitinPatel yes you can show Toast..

Answer (score 0):

```
public Context mContext;
private IResult mResultCallBack;

public CServerRequest(IResult mResultCallBack, Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResultCallBack = mResultCallBack;
}

public void postWalletRequest(final String requestType, String url, JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
         if(jsonObject.getJSONArray.length() == 0) {

    System.out.println("JSONArray is null");      
 }
 else{
      System.out.println("JSONArray is not null");
      //parse your string here         


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                mResultCallBack.notifySuccess(requestType, response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                mResultCallBack.notifyError(requestType, error);

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```